# Mamp server is compiling very slow

Tags: php, php5

I'm running PHP 5.5.3 on a MAMP server, and the "compiling" of my php-file takes quite a lot of time. I've heard that I should disable the caching in the php.ini file, but I can't seem to find anything in the php.ini. Anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable the caching in my php.ini file. (at the bottom of the file). That made it running-on-the-go again.